# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on new AmazonS3Client

Tags: java, amazon-s3

When I try to create a new AmazonS3Client object

```
client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(S3ACCESS_KEY, S3SECRET_KEY));
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
```

My project has the httpcore-4.1.jar included and I can see the HttpRequest.class file in there.  I also have the httpclient-4.1.3.jar included.  Would that have any affect on this?

The project builds just fine and I only run into this error when I create a new AmazonS3Client object.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of banging my head against the wall I ended up just re-cloning the repo and it worked fine.  I must have just screwed up my config in the version I was working on.  Not very satisfying, but it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is a wrong version of http client. Looking at amazonws maven artifact, it is depending on`HttpCLient 4.2.1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Uses HttpClient 4.2.1.

Comment: I just updated both httpcore and httpclient to 4.2.1 and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Try downloading the maven artifact and seeeing what it contains. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.3.14. Maybe there is a conflict between the httpclient you use and the one bundled in amazons3 client?